# colorbox with customize scroller

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, colorbox

every one i am trying to use colorbox with customize scroller bar.
 i am using jquery_custom_scrollbar for custom scroller. and m having problem when the its pop through the colorbox. `$(".pop_me").colorbox({rel:'pop_me', width:"65%"})`

its pops but the scroller is normal but where in static it gives custom scroller

> anyway i messed up with things, can any i suggest me how can i make
>   scrollerbar customize for colorbox.

thanks for your help,
anstrangelover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the color box

```
$(".pop_me").colorbox({rel:'pop_me', width:"65%", onComplete:function(){
// inistialise your scroll pane
}});
```

hope this will work out